# Add/Update Security rules in multiple NSGs

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I would like to Add/update multiple NSG's at once with a new security rule. It should check if a security rule by the same name is already present in NSG, then it should update the rule or else should add a new rule with +10 priority of last rule. It will read the input from csv.

Below script works to read one rule and updates the IP of a particular declare variable, rule name to update, and parameters to update

```
$nsg = Get->AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "Test" -ResourceGroupName "RG-TEST"
$SecurityRuleName = "Port_http"
```

here we are updating IP of source to 127.0.0.2

```
$sourceAddrPrefix = "127.0.0.2"
$rule = ($nsg | Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name
$SecurityRuleName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) if ($rule -eq $null)
{  $prio =
[int]($nsg.SecurityRules[$nsg.SecurityRules.Count-1].Priority)  $prio
+= 10  Write-Host "Adding $SecurityRuleName rule to allow $sourceAddrPrefix with priority $prio"  $ret = ($nsg |
Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $SecurityRuleName `
                -SourceAddressPrefix $sourceAddrPrefix  -SourcePortRange "*" `
                -DestinationAddressPrefix "*" -DestinationPortRange "80" `
                -Protocol "*" -Direction "Inbound" -Access "Allow" `
                 -Priority $prio) } else {  Write-Host "Updating $SecurityRuleName rule to allow $sourceAddrPrefix"  $ret = ($nsg |
 Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $SecurityRuleName `
                -SourceAddressPrefix $sourceAddrPrefix  -SourcePortRange "*" `
                -DestinationAddressPrefix "*" -DestinationPortRange "80" `
                -Protocol "*" -Direction "Inbound" -Access "Allow" `
                -Priority $rule.Priority) } Write-Host "Saving to Azure..." $ret = ($nsg | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup)
```

Comment: What information does the CSV contain?

Comment: @ManjunathRao - Security rules to be created in the NSG.